NiFi DeduplicateRecord processor, RecordPathException when record path provided
I have encountered an issue with DeduplicateRecord processor.
I am trying to setup a flow where I could potentially have duplicated records in a flowfile record.
For the test purposes I have used GenerateRecord processor to produce a flowfile record with 10 JSON objects inside.

Here is the JSON sample:
[{"city":"Pollyside"},{"city":"East Deweytown"},{"city":"Beulahland"},{"city":"Windlerstad"},{"city":"South Rocky"},{"city":"Nicolasachester"},{"city":"Doyleland"},{"city":"Framifort"},{"city":"Bartolettimouth"},{"city":"Lake Carroll"}]

And in DeduplicateRecord processor I have setup a record path property to deduplicate the records on "city" field value.

When the DeduplicateRecord processor is triggered by incoming flowfile, it throws the exception:

2024-07-04 15:18:51,518 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.n.p.standard.DeduplicateRecord DeduplicateRecord[id=7e4ddfab-0190-1000-3ed6-a985fe488c5b] Failed in detecting duplicate records at index 0
org.apache.nifi.record.path.exception.RecordPathException: Unexpected token '' at line 1, column 0. Query:
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.RecordPathParser.displayRecognitionError(RecordPathParser.java:120)
at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.reportError(BaseRecognizer.java:186)
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.RecordPathParser.filter(RecordPathParser.java:1356)
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.RecordPathParser.pathOrFunction(RecordPathParser.java:4415)
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.RecordPathParser.pathExpression(RecordPathParser.java:4468)
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.RecordPath.compile(RecordPath.java:84)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.lambda$newMappingFunction$2(LocalLoadingCache.java:145)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2406)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(Unknown Source)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2404)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2387)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:56)
at org.apache.nifi.record.path.util.RecordPathCache.getCompiled(RecordPathCache.java:34)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.DeduplicateRecord.evaluateKeyFromDynamicProperties(DeduplicateRecord.java:555)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.DeduplicateRecord.onTrigger(DeduplicateRecord.java:470)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1361)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:247)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am using 1.26.0 version of NiFi.
What I am doing wrong here? Any help appreciated.

Ok, answering my own question.
I discovered that there is a difference in documentation.
One way to get information about the processor is by clicking "View usage" in processor menu.

This will open a documentation about the specific processor within NiFi UI.
And NiFi internal documentation for DeduplicateRecord processor states the following:

This is exactly what I did by following internal documentation guides and ended up having an exception.
Now if we look online, the documentation for the same DeduplicateRecord processor, we would see the following:

After changing the DeduplicateRecord processor configuration to match the online documentation I got it working like I expected.

